# Pandas - Groupby with cumsum or cumcount

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have the following dataframe:

```
       Vela    FlgVela  
0         R      0
1         V      1      
2         V      1      
3         R      1      
4         R      1
5         V      0
6         R      1
7         R      1
8         R      1
```

What is the best way to get the result of the dataframe below?

```
       Vela    FlgVela  AddCol
0         R      0         1
1         V      1         2
2         V      1         2
3         R      1         3
4         R      1         3
5         V      0         4
6         R      1         5
7         R      1         5
8         R      1         5
```

I have tried the following logic but the result is not what I expected.

```
df['AddCol'] = df.groupby(df['Vela'].astype(str).str.strip() !=  df['Vela'].shift(-1).astype(str).str.strip() ).cumcount()+1
```

Comment: Please, describe according to which rule the additional column shall be filled.

Comment: The `df['Vela'].astype(str).str.strip()` should be totally unnecessary and makes this very hard to read. It's a code smell that when you read in the dataframe, you handled the dtypes, separators or whitespace wrong, so you got unwanted leading or trailing whitespace. Fix your `pd.read_csv()` settings. Actually if you're casting it to 'string', the dtype might have defaulted to 'object' instead of 'string', so specify `pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'Vela':str, ...})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're close, here is one way:

```
df["AddCol"] = df.groupby("Vela").ngroup().diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

where we first get the group number each distinct `Vela` belongs to (kind of factorize) then take the first differences and see if they are not equal to 0. This will sort of give the "turning" points from one group to another. Then we cumulatively sum them,

to get

```
>>> df

  Vela  FlgVela  AddCol
0    R        0       1
1    V        1       2
2    V        1       2
3    R        1       3
4    R        1       3
5    V        0       4
6    R        1       5
7    R        1       5
8    R        1       5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to group the dataframe. We can compare adjacent rows to create a boolean mask, then calculate cumulative sum on this mask to create a counter

```
df['AddCol'] = df['Vela'].ne(df['Vela'].shift()).cumsum()
```

---

```
  Vela  FlgVela  AddCol
0    R        0       1
1    V        1       2
2    V        1       2
3    R        1       3
4    R        1       3
5    V        0       4
6    R        1       5
7    R        1       5
8    R        1       5
```